# Adapter in Spinner, Android

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner, adapter, android-adapter

How do i set the adapter in Spinner for the following bunch of code? I should set the adapter under

//set adapter for spinner here

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
public ListViewFragment(){}
Spinner mspinner; //declare spinner globally
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

mspinner        = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
//set adapter for spinner here


return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

//do something when particular item is selected from spinner

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
}
```

Comment: do you want to do like this?? see here http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Comment: @R.T.
Actually i dont know how to set adapter. I dont need to customize.

Comment: this example is for customizes spinner,did u see this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//here are the contents its the same as you do in a listview it can be a ArrayList or a array
String[] content={"A","B","C"};
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,content);
mspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

try this hope this will work for you!!

Comment: and where do i put the spinner items?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Hope it works

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        mspinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        //set adapter for spinner here
        // you need to create a  array which one is added to spinner

        String [] name = {"A","B","C"};
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
       // you can use getActivity() or this 

        mspinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;
        }
```

Thank you